# Get available all COM port to tkinter combo box in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, serial-port

I have a **tkinter GUI** with a Combo box.

I want to get all available COM ports to combo box at starting GUI and I need to perform a function while changing combo box value.

I have **pyserial** and I'm using **Python 2.7**.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

This is the function for get COM ports..I want to bind this for  my GUI.And I need a combo box changing event.

```
import sys
import glob
import serial


def serial_ports():


    ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]

    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(serial_ports())
```

I have added this configuration for get the ports in to combo box.

```
self.comboComNum.configure(values=serial_ports())
```

***QUESTION***

How can I implement a more accurate and faster function for get COM ports?

How can I get combo box changing event?

Comment: in question (not in comment) show your code and full error message (Traceback).

Comment: there are many tutorials and examples on internet and in SO - so first use Google. [simple example for combobox](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/combobox-get-selection/main.py)

Comment: BTW: [simple exaple how to read from serial in tkinter using after()](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/read-serial-port/main.py)

Comment: @furas cant you understand my question?There is no any error message and I searched lot for get COM ports in stackoverflow.I got same answer every place.It takes long time to find COM ports..I need a different function/system for that...Plz remove your -1

Comment: This is the system that I found in Google

https://gist.github.com/NandikaSirinuwan/367faf9a6c81571d1b6e572699dd5a62

can you give me a different method for do this same job and how to controls change event in combo box in tkinter?

Comment: How can I put a code ?because,I dont know about that...and How this is useless for others?
I will add some code...But all people can easily find it using Google.

Comment: I UPDATED the question..Is it OK now?Can you answer please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130803/discussion-between-user119o-and-furas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is  [serial.tools.list_ports](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html) and maybe it will work faster (I don't use Windows so I can test it)

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

print serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
```

---

You got in comment link to example [combobox-get-selection](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/combobox-get-selection/main.py)

Here shorter version

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports

# --- functions ---

def serial_ports():    
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

def on_select(event=None):

    # get selection from event    
    print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())

    # or get selection directly from combobox
    print("comboboxes: ", cb.get())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=serial_ports())
cb.pack()

# assign function to combobox
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: its work on windows.
https://gist.github.com/NandikaSirinuwan/b2c0225f994a831eac1f1802822fb3c4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Muestra los Puertos COM en Python
import serial.tools.list_ports
# Llamamos a la libreria que nos ayudara a buscar
# los puertos habilidatos.


find_com = serial.tools.list_ports

COM = find_com.comports()

#Nos devuelve una lista
# EL primer parametro es el puerto.
print(COM[0]) # Nombre completo del puerto.
print(COM[0][0]) # Solo puerto COM#
```